# Native location based notifications in iOS 8 still fire after being cancelled

Tags: ios, ios8, uilocalnotification

First I schedule LocalNotification with a region:

```
(lldb) po [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]
<__NSArrayM 0x7fca91ec32d0>(
<UIConcreteLocalNotification: 0x7fca91ed4990>{region = CLCircularRegion (identifier:'LocationID0', center:<+38.00000000,-122.00000000>, radius:50.00m), regionTriggersOnce = NO, user info = {}} )
```

and it fires each time i get in or out of the region. All good so far!

But at a certain point i want to remove the notification. I do that with

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

Here are the scheduled notifications now:

```
(lldb) po [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]
<__NSArrayM 0x7fca91e89a30>(

)
```

After this, the same notification fires each time I arrive/exit the region. 
How can I cancel the notification?